# Sequelize - query with or operator and model association

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

With *Sequelize*, I have two models with **many to many** association : `User` and `Category`.
I want to get all categories that belongs to the current user, and also  categories with a certain property, but I don't understand how, with only one query...

I'm using the `Op.or` operator, according to the [documentation](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/querying.html#operators), and the `$Model.attribute$` syntax for associated model (seen [here](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/models-usage.html#top-level-where-with-eagerly-loaded-models)).

```
let categories = await models.category.findAll({
        where: {
            [Op.or]: [
                { someCategoryProperty: true },
                { '$User.id$': req.currentUser.id },
            ],
        },
        include: [{
            model: models.user,
            as: 'User',
        }],
    });
```

The operator works if I add 2 conditions about the Category model, but how to add a condition on the association ?

Comment: You have to put the user filter inside the include, you'll have "2" `where`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the tips :

Actually, `$Model.attribute$` wasn't the good pattern, `$database_table_name.attribute$` is the good one.

With the `'$..$'` syntax, we must use the **database table name**, and not the model.
If my model is called `user`, Sequelize set the database name **`users`** !

So this code works :

```
let categories = await models.category.findAll({
        where: {
            [Op.or]: [
                { someCategoryProperty: true },
                { '$users.id$': req.currentUser.id },
            ],
        },
        include: [{
            model: models.user,
        }],
    });
```

Thanks